# How to include git revision into angular-cli application?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to display git revision on my angular2 application's about page. The project is based on angular-cli.

How can build be extended so git revision is put for example into `environment.ts` or other place accessible to application?

Comment: I guess the *Angular-cli* lacks a needed pre-build scripting functionality. But you might use the plain *NPM scripting*, I guess.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As suggested by @Yuri, I was able to solve this by using `npm` scripting.

1. Defined `git.version.ts` in the root of the angular-cli project:

```js
import { Observable, combineLatest } from 'rxjs'

declare var require: any;
declare var process: any;

const fs = require('fs');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

const revision = new Observable<string>(s => {
    exec('git rev-parse --short HEAD',
        (error: Error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log('git error: ' + error + stderr);
            }
            s.next(stdout.toString().trim());
            s.complete();
        });
});

const branch = new Observable<string>(s => {
    exec('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD',
        (error: Error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log('git error: ' + error + stderr);
            }
            s.next(stdout.toString().trim());
            s.complete();
        });
});

combineLatest(revision, branch)
    .subscribe(([revision, branch]) => {
        console.log(`version: '${process.env.npm_package_version}', revision: '${revision}', branch: '${branch}'`);

        const content = '// this file is automatically generated by git.version.ts script\n' +
            `export const versions = {version: '${process.env.npm_package_version}', revision: '${revision}', branch: '${branch}'};`;

        fs.writeFileSync(
            'src/environments/versions.ts',
            content,
            {encoding: 'utf8'}
        );
    });
```

2. Added pre-build hook in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    ...
    "start": "ng serve --proxy proxy-config.json",
    "prebuild.prod": "ts-node -O \"{\\\"module\\\":\\\"commonjs\\\"}\" git.version.ts",
    "build.prod": "ng build -prod",
    ...
}
```

3. Use the generated `src/environments/versions.ts` in the application.

   **UPDATE 10/2018:** Here is the more-readable version of the script, rxjs-version-agnostic:

```js
import { writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import { dedent } from 'tslint/lib/utils';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import * as child from 'child_process';
const exec = promisify(child.exec);

async function createVersionsFile(filename: string) {
  const revision = (await exec('git rev-parse --short HEAD')).stdout.toString().trim();
  const branch = (await exec('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD')).stdout.toString().trim();

  console.log(`version: '${process.env.npm_package_version}', revision: '${revision}', branch: '${branch}'`);

  const content = dedent`
      // this file is automatically generated by git.version.ts script
      export const versions = {
        version: '${process.env.npm_package_version}',
        revision: '${revision}',
        branch: '${branch}'
      };`;

  writeFileSync(filename, content, {encoding: 'utf8'});
}

createVersionsFile('src/environments/versions.ts');
```

Note, when using angular-cli v7.0.6, I also had to change script invocation in the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "prebuild.prod": "ts-node -O '{\"module\": \"commonjs\"}' git.version.ts",
    ...
}
```

Comment: ```ts-node git.version.ts``` command does not work and I don't know why
I geting this: 

```Did you mean one of these?
    rebuild
    prefix
    profile```

Comment: For anyone coming to this using `angular 6` / `rxjs 6`: change the import to `import { Observable, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';`, and then replace `Observable.combineLatest` with just `combineLatest`.

Comment: This was a beautiful solution, but I also suggest adding the tag: `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`

Comment: How to generate the src/environments/versions.ts file? I call the `ng prebuild.prod` command but nothing happens. I wait for several minutes but no output. My versions:
```bash
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.10

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/pwa                      0.6.5
@angular/service-worker           5.2.11
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.5
rxjs                              5.5.10
```

Comment: this is a very clean and nice way to acheive it!!! i thought sharing a code that i added to this solution that will print out more git information and jobname or BUILD_NUMBER if you are running it through jenkins

Comment: here is the additional code: add 4 more observables
lastCommitTime which is git log --format="%ai" -n1 HEAD, 
lastCommitMessage which is git log --format="%B" -n1 HEAD, 
lastCommitAuthor which is git log --format="%aN" -n1 HEAD, 
lastCommitNumber which is git rev-list --count HEAD, 
const commitSHA = process.env.GIT_COMMIT || branch;
const buildInfo = process.env.BUILD_NUMBER || 'LOCAL ' + revision + ' - last commit number ' + lastCommitNumber + ', by ' + lastCommitAuthor + ' on ' + lastCommitTime;
const jobName = process.env.JOB_NAME || 'local build'

Comment: `-O '{\"module\": \"commonjs\"}'` in package.json didn't work for me (win10). I had to remove it and change the imports in git.version.ts to require statements.

Comment: @MIWMIB yeah I had the same. At first it worked fine on my macos and build server (linux) but was failing on windoze with `'ts-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: After updating Angular the error `Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to "ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective",...` appeared. Updating the package ts-node with command `npm update ts-node` solved this for me. see [False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective` in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72488958/false-expression-non-string-value-passed-to-ts-resolvetypereferencedirective)

Answer (score 25):

The other answers were helpful, but I preferred a more simple, direct approach. Here's mine.

Run `npm install git-describe --save-dev`. Then add `git-version.js` to the root:

```javascript
// This script runs operations *synchronously* which is normally not the best
// approach, but it keeps things simple, readable, and for now is good enough.

const { gitDescribeSync } = require('git-describe');
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs');

const gitInfo = gitDescribeSync();
const versionInfoJson = JSON.stringify(gitInfo, null, 2);

writeFileSync('git-version.json', versionInfoJson);
```

Optionally you can add `/git-version.json` to your `.gitignore` file.

Update your `package.json` to do something like this:

```javascript
"scripts": {
  "build": "node git-version.js && ng build"
}
```

Then add `version-info.ts` to the root of your project:

```javascript
export const versionInfo = (() => {
  try {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-var-requires
    return require('../../git-version.json');
  } catch {
    // In dev the file might not exist:
    return { tag: 'v0.0.0', hash: 'dev' };
  }
})();
```

And `import` the `versionInfo` in your `app.component.ts` or anywhere else you'd want to use it.

Comment: npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.2: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: Strange. I ran this on my Windows 10 x64 machine without problems, and it runs fine on AppVeyor's VS2017 image too.

Comment: @wildloop The npm syntax to install `git-describe` should be `npm install git-describe --save-dev`

Answer (score 17):

1. Add `git-version.js` to the root.This code will execute git commands and write the output to the `git-version.json` file.

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs');

const longSHA = childProcess.execSync("git rev-parse HEAD").toString().trim();
const shortSHA = childProcess.execSync("git rev-parse --short HEAD").toString().trim();
const branch = childProcess.execSync('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').toString().trim();
const authorName = childProcess.execSync("git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an'").toString().trim();
const commitTime = childProcess.execSync("git log -1 --pretty=format:'%cd'").toString().trim();
const commitMsg = childProcess.execSync("git log -1 --pretty=%B").toString().trim();
const totalCommitCount = childProcess.execSync("git rev-list --count HEAD").toString().trim();

const versionInfo = {
    shortSHA: shortSHA,
    SHA : longSHA,
    branch: branch,
    lastCommitAuthor: authorName,
    lastCommitTime: commitTime,
    lastCommitMessage: commitMsg,
    lastCommitNumber: totalCommitCount
}

const versionInfoJson = JSON.stringify(versionInfo, null, 2);

writeFileSync('/src/git-version.json', versionInfoJson);
```

This code will generate the `git-version.json` file :-

```json
{
  "shortSHA": "0e786d4",
  "SHA": "0e786d4ad3778463f6f30c28f254cc85c24eb4b3",
  "branch": "master",
  "lastCommitAuthor": "'saurabh'",
  "lastCommitTime": "'Thu Apr 9 12:59:16 2020 +0530'",
  "lastCommitMessage": "Commit message",
  "lastCommitNumber": "200"
}
```

Modify above code as per your requirements.

Run: `node git-version.js` This will generate the `git-version.json` into `src` directory.

2. To run this code before or after the build. add a new script to `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build.prod": "node git-version.js && ng build --prod"
  }
```

3. Run:-  `npm run build.prod`

**suggestions for code improvement are welcome :)**

Comment: This worked great, my only critique is that you misspelled the variable `chidProcess`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.fixed that issue

Comment: nice one! You can add `version: process.env.npm_package_version,` to add the version in the json file produced.

Comment: Nice! with more git information.

Answer (score 10):

I like to keep things simple. Can add to your index.html:

```html
<script>window.version = '{git-hash}';</script>
```

Then add a `postbuild` script to your `package.json`:

```
"postbuild": "sed -i '' \"s/{git\\-hash}/$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)/g\" dist/*/index.html"
```

Not elegant by any means. Personally I create an object on `window` with various information about the build (time, version, and a release summary link).

To stay more 'pure', stick the `{git-hash}` string in `environment.prod.ts` and run the `sed` against all `main-*.js` files produced.

```
"postbuild": "sed -i '' \"s/{git\\-hash}/$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)/g\" dist/*/main-*.js"
```

Note you'll always see '{git-hash}' running locally as it's only replaced post-build.
If you replace it before the build, obviously can't replace it on future builds locally and would most definitely accidentally check that in.

---- UPDATE ----

Ended up creating a library to pull various information. Only ended up using version, build time, and commitTime personally.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rippell/ngx-build-info

Comment: this is probably only for systems which have `sed` command (linux:Yes, windows: No)

Comment: Absolutely true, partially why I ended up creating the npm library

Answer (score 8):

### Display branch name and commit hash

I have a little different approach, inspired by answers [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56167604/860099) [Seba Arce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54022521/860099) and [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51154524/860099) , in main project directory:

- execute: `npm install git-rev-sync --save` (this lib give acces to hash and branch name)
- add file `git-version-gen.js` with following body

```js
const git  = require('git-rev-sync');
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs');

const gitInfo = { commit: git.short(), commitLong: git.long(), branch: git.branch() };
const ts = 'export const gitVersion = ' + JSON.stringify(gitInfo, null, 2);

writeFileSync('src/environments/git-version.ts', ts);
```

- in `package.json` in `scripts` add `"build": "node git-version-gen.js && ng build ..."`
- in your main app file e.g. `app.component.ts` use it as follows

```js
import { gitVersion } from '../../../environments/git-version';

// ...

  constructor() {
    console.log(`GIT branch:`,gitVersion.branch);
    console.log(`GIT commit:`,gitVersion.commit);
  }
```

What are advantages of use this?

- we create here `src/environments/git-version.ts` file so this is TypeScript, not .json - similar like you environments files - this will turn on support from your code editor (e.g VSCode)
- you have acces to commit hash nad branch name (lib `git-describe` not gives acces to branch name)
- if you commit generated `git-version.ts` file instead put it to `.gitignore` then project will run without build (e.g. by `ng serve ...`) and fresh developers will not be confused that there is missing some 'mystic' file... - however choice is up to you.
- cross platform - tested on Azure (windows), MacOs (~linux-like)

Answer (score 2):

I went with a modified version of Vilmantas Baranauskas

I moved `src/index.html` to `src/index.base.html` and added an empty `<meta name="revision" content="">` inside the HEAD

Example:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MySuperAwesome Angular</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="revision" content="">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Then modified `git.version.ts` like this:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';

import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const indexBasePath = join(__dirname, 'src');

const exec = require('child_process').exec;

const revObs = new Observable<string>(s => {
    exec('git rev-parse --short HEAD',
    function (error: Error, stdout: Buffer, stderr: Buffer) {
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('git error: ' + error + stderr);
        }
        s.next(stdout.toString().trim());
        s.complete();
    });
});

const branchObs = new Observable<string>(s => {
    exec('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD',
    function (error: Error, stdout: Buffer, stderr: Buffer) {
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('git error: ' + error + stderr);
        }
        s.next(stdout.toString().trim());
        s.complete();
    });
});

Observable
    .combineLatest(revObs, branchObs)
    .subscribe(([revision, branch]) => {
        console.log(`revision: '${revision}', branch: '${branch}'`);

        const baseHTML = readFileSync(join(indexBasePath, 'index.base.html'), 'utf8');
        const html = baseHTML
          .replace('<meta name="revision" content="">', `<meta name="revision" content="${ revision }">`);

        writeFileSync(
          join(indexBasePath, 'index.html'),
          html,
          { encoding: 'utf8' }
        );
    });
```

In this example I only put revision, but you can be more thorough and put branch and version inside your html HEAD section

Answer (score 2):

For angular 6

1 Install git-describe as a dev dependency

```
 npm i git-describe -s
```

2 On your root project create a grab-git-info.js

```
   const { gitDescribeSync } = require('git-describe');
   const { writeFileSync } = require('fs');
   const path = require('path');
   const info = gitDescribeSync();
   const infoJson = JSON.stringify(info, null, 2);
   writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/src/git-version.json'), infoJson);
```

The output of the grab-git-info.js script will be the ‘git-version.json’ file under /src/ which will contain all the git info needed by our app.

In order to be able to import the json file (or any other json file) we need to add a definition file declaring of the added module so that the Typescript compiler will recognize it.

3. Under your /src create typings.d.ts file (read more about typings.d.ts here: https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#typescript-typings)

/src/typings.d.ts:

```
 declare module '*.json' {
   const value: any;
   export default value;
 }
```

From this point on you can import any json file located under /src as a module!

In your component you can import this json

```
 import * as data from '../../../git-version.json';
 ...
 public git = data;
```

In the html

```
 Rev: {{git.hash}}
```

Finally
 Add and most important, run the script before build

In package.json add:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "node grab-git-info && ng build",
```

And run the app with

```
 npm run build
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done it by generating prebuild script run on postinstall and run before any angular related script

```js
const fs =  require('fs');
const git = require('git-rev-sync');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

const releaseTag = git.tag();
const template = `export const gitTag = '${releaseTag}';\n`;

mkdirp('./generated', function(err) {
    fs.writeFileSync('./generated/git-tag.ts', template, { encoding: 'UTF-8' });
});
```

which generated git-tag.ts file:

```js
export const gitTag = 'xxxxxxx';
```

and now u just use in component

```js
import { gitTag } from '[pathToRoot]/generated/git-tag';
```

also add
 .gitignore

`generated`

Comment: what is require('fs'), require('git-rev-sync') and require('mkdirp') do i need to install them

Answer (score 0):

Use gulp task using gulp-replace and git-rev-sync to add the hash and branch on build :

1) Create the gulp task

```
var gulp            =    require('gulp'),
    replace         =    require('gulp-replace'),
    git             =    require('git-rev-sync'),

gulp.task('git', function () {
    gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(replace('{{git-branch}}', git.branch()))
        .pipe(replace('{{git-hash}}', git.short()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/'))
});

// Build Tasks
gulp.task('build', ['git']);
```

2) Add the following code to index.html :

```
{{git-branch}}@{{git-hash}}
```

3) Run

```
gulp build
```