# How to inject commit hash in environtment.ts in angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is it possible to generate environment object asynchronously?

**Reason:** I would like to have available commit hash in my application. Idea is to use `environment.ts` file. However to obtain current commit hash I need asynchronous call (eg. using [git-rev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-rev)).

I tried to inject variable from environment variables using process.env: `$ VERSION=123 ng serve`

```
declare var process: any;

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  version: process.env.VERSION
};
```

But this results in undefined version.

Comment: You can make async calls in the environment file but I don't think that will help you get a correct commit hash as it will be evaluated at runtime in the users browser. Why do you want to have the commit hash in the environment file?

Comment: Oh I didnt know its evaluated at runtime. Thought its evaluated during build. Is there any other way to inject commit message to my project? Lets say I want to display commit message in some component.

Comment: Are you coupling your dev environment to your components or are you arbitrarily displaying commit messages? If it's the prior then I would be thinking some sort of commit hook that writes the commit to the environment file.

Comment: I use SentryIO as Error Handler and it allows you to specify version currently running. I would like to include commit hash in that version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this question : [How to include git revision into angular-cli application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155115/how-to-include-git-revision-into-angular-cli-application)

There is also a discussion on github on this related subject, which it will be easier to add possibility to pass environment variables to `environment.ts` : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4318