# How to display Git branch name on Angular App

Tags: angular, git, azure-devops, web-deployment, git-branch

I have an angular application only - no backend

I want to display my private branch name in my angular application (e.x. myName/myFeature)

I'm using Azure DevOps for deploy my app in the cloud

I searched the web for tutorials\guides but I think I'm missing something.

The best tutorial I've found is this:
https://www.taithienbo.com/replacing-variables-in-an-angular-app-using-replace-token-extension/

But still it is not working, it is not displaying the correct branch name.

[image]

Code:

- component.ts

  import {environment} from '../../../../environments/environment';
  version: string = environment.version;
- component.html

  {{version}}
- environment.ts

  version: '#{Build.BuildNumber}#'

DevOps:

[image]

[image]

It is displaying the wrong branch name, the upper instead of the bottom:

[image]

Comment: Could you show us your code and build pipeline? If you followed this tuotrial I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Better, but still not enough, please share with us your pipeline and logs for this task.

Comment: Sure, is it enough?

Comment: I would use the build scripts (npm build) to generate the file - that way it works also if you build locally and not only on DevOps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155115/how-to-include-git-revision-into-angular-cli-application

Answer (score 0):

In the build config the setting you're looking for is here;[image]

Following that link you can find the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) which (although for yaml pipelines) gives an example;

```
$(TeamProject)_$(Build.DefinitionName)_$(SourceBranchName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
```

For your purposes you'd just want

```
$(SourceBranchName)
```

Comment: You are suggesting to change the build the number to be the branch name. I want the build number to stay as it is and still to display the branch name in the application

Comment: Understood. I was mostly working off the final image you posted. I'll post a new answer if I come up with something.